# Creational Patterns for Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, ninject, object-construction

I'm specifically using C# with Ninject but the problem stretches beyond just Ninject.  My problem is that I have a few classes all with different constructor arguments plus the injected ones.  I know I can use `kernel.Get<MyObject>(constructor args here)` to instantiate the objects.  This doesn't feel right to me as I'd have the kernel all over the place. I'll do my best to list examples below.

What I have now:

```
public interface IStore<T>
{
    void CommitToDatabase(T item);
}

public abstract class Thing
{
    private IStore<Thing> _store;

    protected Thing(object key, IStore<Thing> store)
    {
        Key = key;
        _store = store;
    }

    public object Key { get; private set; }

    public virtual void Update()
    {
        _store.CommitToDatabase(this);
    }
}

public class Person :Thing
{
    public Person(object key, string name, int age, IStore<Thing> store)
        : base(key, store)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }
}

public class Car :Thing
{
    public Car(object key, int year, string make, string model, IStore<Thing> store)
        : base(key, store)
    {
        Year = year;
        Make = make;
        Model = model;
    }

    public int Year { get; private set; }    
    public string Make { get; private set; }
    public string Model { get; private set; }
}
```

I know in Ninject I can do the following:

```
kernel.Get<Car>(new ConstructorArgument("key", 1), new ConstructorArgument("year", 2010), new ConstructorArgument("make", "Astin Martin"), new ConstructorArgument("model", "Vanquish"));
```

but that doesn't feel right to me.  What I was thinking of doing was to change it to have an Initialize method, but I'm not sure if this is best-practice or if there's a better way.

Possible new stuff:

```
public interface IStore<T>
{
    void CommitToDatabase(T item);
}

public abstract class Thing
{
    private IStore<Thing> _store;

    protected bool _isInitialised;

    protected Thing(IStore<Thing> store)
    {
        Key = null;
        _store = store;
        _isInitialised = false;
    }

    public object Key { get; private set; }

    public virtual void Initialize(object key)
    {
        if (!_isInitialised) {
            Key = key;
            _isInitialised = true;
        }
    }

    public virtual void Update()
    {
        _store.CommitToDatabase(this);
    }

    protected bool IsInitialised()
    {
        return _isInitialised;
    }
}

public class Person :Thing
{
    public Person(IStore<Thing> store)
        : base(store)
    {
        Name = string.Empty;
        Age = int.MinValue;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }

    public void Initialize(object key, string name, int age)
    {
        if (!base.IsInitialised()) {
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
        }

        base.Initialize(key);
    }
}

public class Car :Thing
{
    public Car(IStore<Thing> store)
        : base(store)
    {
        Year = 0;
        Make = "Ford";
        Model = "Model T";
    }

    public int Year { get; private set; }
    public string Make { get; private set; }
    public string Model { get; private set; }

    public void Initialize(object key, int year, string make, string model)
    {
        if (!base.IsInitialised()) {
            Year = year;
            Make = make;
            Model = model;
        }

        base.Initialize(key);
    }
}
```

**Question:**
Is the 'Possible new stuff' a common practice, bad idea, good idea with poor implementation, or is there a better way to do it altogether?

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to have your entities aware of the persistence mechanism in the first place. You might think about using the Repository pattern instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't inject IStore into your DTO's. They should be plain objects. Instead inject `IStore<IThing>` into the classes that currently call `Update` and call `CommitToDatabase` from there.

e.g.

```
public class PersonService
{
    private readonly IStore<Person> store;
    public PersonService(IStore<Person> store)
    {
       this.store = store;
    }

    public void CreatePerson(string name, int age)
    {
       var person = new Person(name, age);
       this.store.CommitToDatabase(person);
    }
}
```

Also DTOs like Person shouldn't be created using an IoC container. Get them from your persistence layer, create them using AutoMapper or create them using `new`. But do not use an IoC container for them. They shouldn't have any dependencies.